# How to get dtypes of columns in julia dataframe

Tags: julia

How to get dtypes of all columns and particular column(s) in julia. To be specific what is the pandas equivalent of `df.dtypes` in julia?

For example,
I have a df like below,

```
│ Row │ Id    │ name   │ item location │
│     │ Int64 │ String │ String        │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼───────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ A      │ xyz           │
│ 2   │ 2     │ B      │ abc           │
│ 3   │ 3     │ C      │ def           │
│ 4   │ 4     │ D      │ ghi           │
│ 5   │ 5     │ E      │ xyz           │
│ 6   │ 6     │ F      │ abc           │
│ 7   │ 7     │ G      │ def           │
│ 8   │ 8     │ H      │ ghi           │
│ 9   │ 9     │ I      │ xyz           │
│ 10  │ 10    │ J      │ abc           │
```

Expected output:

```
{'id':  Int64, 'name': String, 'item location': String}
```

How to get dtypes, i.e., `Int64 │ String │ String`  in Julia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified two different expected outputs so I show here how to get both:

```
julia> df = DataFrame("Id" => 1, "name" => "A", "item_location" => "xyz")
1×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ Id    │ name   │ item_location │
│     │ Int64 │ String │ String        │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼───────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ A      │ xyz           │

julia> eltype.(eachcol(df))
3-element Array{DataType,1}:
 Int64
 String
 String

julia> Dict(names(df) .=> eltype.(eachcol(df)))
Dict{String,DataType} with 3 entries:
  "Id"            => Int64
  "name"          => String
  "item_location" => String
```

additionally, if you wanted to store the result in a `DataFrame` instead of a `Dict` you can write (see `mapcols` documentation [here](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/latest/lib/functions/#DataFrames.mapcols)):

```
julia> mapcols(eltype, df)
1×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ Id       │ name     │ item_location │
│     │ DataType │ DataType │ DataType      │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────────┤
│ 1   │ Int64    │ String   │ String        │
```

And if you would want to have a `NamedTuple` storing this information write (the documentation of `Tables.columntable` is [here](https://juliadata.github.io/Tables.jl/dev/#Tables.columntable)):

```
julia> map(eltype, Tables.columntable(df))
(Id = Int64, name = String, item_location = String)
```

(in this case note that for very wide tables this might have some extra compilation cost as each time you call it you potentially get a new type of `NamedTuple`)

Comment: this is exactly what i want. It would be great if you add the link of official doc.

Comment: The beauty is that the basic solution is not DataFrames.jl specific. It is just Julia Base applied to a data frame. This is pretty common in Julia, as things compose very well. We just use broadcasting (the `.`), `eltype` (from Base) and `eachcol` (also from Base). `mapcols` and `Tables.columntable` are package specific - I will add links to the docs for them. In general this is a very different philosophy to Pandas, where most of the functionality is packed into one package. In Julia packages can have much more limited API as multiple dispatch can handle the composition part.

Comment: oh that's really nice. I am a naive julia learner. Since I am new to julia, sorry If my questions are dumb to Julia Community.

Comment: The opposite - these are excellent questions. For people new to Julia the key thing to know is that: 1) you should learn Base Julia really well, 2) most of the packages will then try to maximally leverage this knowledge. In the long run (after you learn Base) it means that you have much less to learn when you start working with a new package and that you can expect two completely unrelated packages "just work" together out of the box, without any glue interface. A good example is https://julialang.org/blog/2019/01/fluxdiffeq/ that shows mixing differential equations and deep learning packages.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `describe(df)` which is a catchall for learning about the columns in your data frame.

Comment: This gives me; variable name, mean, min, median, max, nunique and nmissing in each column AND data type. Good job.

Comment: And `describe(df, :eltype)` gets you a two-column dataframe with just the names (as `Symbol`) and the eltype (as `DataType`)